# MySQL table and query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql

The following is my table: gps_gotaxiking

```
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| RecordID  | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| CarNo     | varchar(10)         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| Valid     | varchar(48)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lon       | varchar(13)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lat       | varchar(13)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| angle     | varchar(10)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| speed     | varchar(10)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| CarStatus | varchar(10)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Time      | datetime            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Current almost 100 million rows data in my database.
And I queried using following code:

```
SELECT lat, lon 
FROM gps_gotaxiking
WHERE `CarNo` = "XXXX"
AND Time BETWEEN 'yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00' AND 'yyyy-mm-dd 23:59:59'
AND Valid = 'Normal';
```

I can get the result, but its return time is above 1 min,
is there any way to simplify the query and reduce the process time?

Comment: Why do you use almost very time the varchar data type?

Comment: How many rows match `CarNo = "XXXX"`?

Comment: How about adding an index to CarNo?

Answer (score 0):

Put a key on the columns `Valid` and `Time`. Think about using integer columns for `Valid`! Access time should be below a second.

Comment: can I add a composite index on (CarNo, Valid , Time)?

Comment: I would usually do single keys on each columns.. but this requires some more knowledge about your data.

Answer (score 0):

Add a composite index on `(CarNo, Time)` to optimize this query:

```
CREATE INDEX car_time on gps_gotaxiking (CarNo, Time);
```

Comment: `Valid` do not add to the composite index together?

Comment: If the first two columns are discriminating enough, that may be overkill.